# Wxpython Phoenix editable listctrl unable to access the changed data

Tags: wxpython

Prior to Phoenix an editable listctrl used to pass back the edited text via the event in `event.Label`.
Using wxpython 4.0.0b2 (Linux) this is no longer appears to be the case.
Looking at the code, the text should be passed back in `event.Item.Text` but it is always blank.

The only way that I have found of by-passing this is to edit the "listctrl.py" mixin itself, adding an extra line of code to the `CloseEditor` function, where I set `event.String` to return the altered text and then access that when the `wx.EVT_LIST_END_LABEL_EDIT` binding is triggered.
It would have been better to set `event.Label` but the `SetLabel` function seems to have been lost along the way.

I feel sure that I must have missed something somewhere.
In short, does anyone know how to access the label that has been altered in the TextEditMixin in wxpython Phoenix?
What I am struggling with appears to be an `EVT_LIST_END_LABEL_EDIT` event with no access to the label itself.
Example code:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix

class EditableListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin):
    ''' TextEditMixin allows any column to be edited. '''

    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
        listmix.TextEditMixin.__init__(self)

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        rows = [("Ford", "Taurus", "1996", "Blue"),
                ("Nissan", "370Z", "2010", "Green"),
                ("Porche", "911", "2009", "Red")
                ]
        self.list_ctrl = EditableListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Make")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Model")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, "Year")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(3, "Color")
        index = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.list_ctrl.InsertItem(index, row[0])
            self.list_ctrl.SetItem(index, 1, row[1])
            self.list_ctrl.SetItem(index, 2, row[2])
            self.list_ctrl.SetItem(index, 3, row[3])
            index += 1
        self.text0 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "Ford", size=(50,30))
        self.text1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "Taurus", size=(50,30))
        self.text2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "1996", size=(50,30))
        self.text3 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "Blue", size=(50,30))
        self.list_ctrl.Select(0)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer2.Add(self.text0, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer2.Add(self.text1, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer2.Add(self.text2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer2.Add(self.text3, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(sizer2,0,wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.OnItemSelected)
        self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_END_LABEL_EDIT, self.OnMixUpdate)

    def OnItemSelected(self, event):
        self.currentItem = event.GetIndex()
        rowid = self.list_ctrl.GetItem(self.currentItem,0)
        self.SetData()
        event.Skip()

    def SetData(self):
        rowid = self.list_ctrl.GetItem(self.currentItem,0)
        self.text0.SetValue(rowid.GetText())
        rowid = self.list_ctrl.GetItem(self.currentItem,1)
        self.text1.SetValue(rowid.GetText())
        rowid = self.list_ctrl.GetItem(self.currentItem,2)
        self.text2.SetValue(rowid.GetText())
        rowid = self.list_ctrl.GetItem(self.currentItem,3)
        self.text3.SetValue(rowid.GetText())

    def OnMixUpdate(self, event):
        self.currentItem = event.GetIndex()
        rowid = event.GetIndex()
        new_data = event.GetLabel()
        new_data2 = event.Item.GetText()
        colid = event.GetColumn ()
        print ("row,col,new label:",rowid,colid,new_data)
        print ("2nd attempt:",new_data2)
        self.list_ctrl.SetItem(rowid,colid,new_data,)
        #Update the textctrl on screen
        self.SetData()
        #Update database
        #self.OnUpdate(None)
        event.Skip()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Editable List Control")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug and was fixed in wx.python 4.0.0